# Python: exe file from script, significant performance decrese

Tags: python, performance, slowdown

I am testing a C++ code compiled to exe (O errors, 0 warnings). The code represents a console application. I run the apllication in the following ways:

a) from the windows7 command line: average time 497sec

b) from Python script using

```
subprocess.call ()
```

with the average time 1201 sec!

**Results:**

The application runs almost 3 tines longer from Python script than from command line... Is this significant performance decrease normal ?

Comment: what's your C++ code do?

Answer (score 2):

Are you measuring from the point that `subprocess.call()` is executed or from the point that you load the Python script? I would imagine that a large portion of that time arises from waiting for the Python interpreter to load, the `subprocess` module to load, any other modules you import, etc. If your Python script which calls the program will end up being large then I think this will become insignificant. If it will be short, you may be better off creating a Windows batch (.bat) file to call the program (assuming those still exist in Win7...I haven't used Windows in a while).

Comment: The time measurment starts on running exe file and it is a part of the cpp file...

Comment: Could you clarify what is doing the actual timing computation? Do you mean that you coded it into the cpp file so that the exe times itself?